# Why are the channels "Debug" and "Analytic" not available for my ETW-EventSource implementation?

Tags: c#, debugging, logging, etw, etw-eventsource

I am using [Microsoft EventSource Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource/) to implement a logging mechanism for my web application.

This library provides four logging event channels: "Admin", "Operational", "Debug" and "Analytic". The Admin and the Operational channel are working fine, the channels are visible and I am able to log events.

For some reason the Debug and the Analytic channel do not appear in the Event Viewer as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

You can see my EventSource implementation below. Additionally I have uploaded the full Visual Studio project including a console test application [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=A88FAA980311A33A!94833&cid=A88FAA980311A33A).

Does anyone know why only Admin and Operational is available?

```
public static partial class WebAppEventSourceHandler
{
    [EventSource(Name = "Company-MyProject-WebApp")]
    private sealed class WebAppEventSource : EventSource
    {
        [Event(1, Message = "Instance: [{0}] Exception Type: [{1}] Exception Message: [{2}] Exception Stack Trace: [{3}] Inner Exception Type: [{4}] Inner Exception Message: [{5}] Inner Exception Stack Trace: [{6}]",
            Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Level = EventLevel.Critical, Version = 1)]
        internal void UnhandledException(string instance, string exceptionType, string exceptionMessage, string exceptionStackTrace,
            string innerExceptionType, string innerExceptionMessage, string innerExceptionStackTrace)
        {
            WriteEvent(1, instance, exceptionType, exceptionMessage, exceptionStackTrace, innerExceptionMessage,
                innerExceptionType, innerExceptionMessage, innerExceptionStackTrace);
        }

        [Event(2, Message = "Instance: [{0}] Controller: [{1}] Action: [{2}] Client Message: [{3}] Server Message: [{4}] Parameter: [{5}]",
            Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Level = EventLevel.Error, Version = 1)]
        internal void LogControllerActionError(string instance, string controller, string action,
            string clientSideMessage, string serverSideMessage, string parameter)
        {
            WriteEvent(2, instance, controller, action, clientSideMessage, serverSideMessage, parameter);
        }

        [Event(3, Message = "Instance: [{0}] Controller: [{1}] Action: [{2}] Client Message: [{3}] Server Message: [{4}] Parameter: [{5}]",
            Channel = EventChannel.Operational, Level = EventLevel.Warning, Version = 1)]
        internal void LogControllerActionWarning(string instance, string controller, string action,
            string clientSideMessage, string serverSideMessage, string parameter)
        {
            WriteEvent(3, instance, controller, action, clientSideMessage, serverSideMessage, parameter);
        }

        [Event(4, Message = "Instance: [{0}] Controller: [{1}] Action: [{2}] Message: [{3}] Server Parameter: [{4}]",
            Channel = EventChannel.Operational, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Version = 1)]
        internal void LogControllerActionInfo(string instance, string controller, string action,
            string message, string parameter)
        {
            WriteEvent(4, instance, controller, action, message, parameter);
        }

        [Event(5, Message = "Instance: [{0}] Controller: [{1}] Action: [{2}] Message: [{3}] Server Parameter: [{4}]",
            Channel = EventChannel.Debug, Level = EventLevel.Verbose, Version = 1)]
        internal void LogControllerActionDebug(string instance, string controller, string action,
            string message, string parameter)
        {
            WriteEvent(5, instance, controller, action, message, parameter);
        }

        [Event(6, Message = "Instance: [{0}] Controller: [{1}] Action: [{2}] Message: [{3}] Server Parameter: [{4}]",
            Channel = EventChannel.Analytic, Level = EventLevel.Verbose, Version = 1)]
        internal void LogControllerActionAnalytic(string instance, string controller, string action,
            string message, string parameter)
        {
            WriteEvent(6, instance, controller, action, message, parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this cmd snippet to register the eventsource:

C:\CustomEventSources>wevtutil.exe im EventSourceExample.Company-MyProject-WebApp.etwManifest.man /rf:"C:\CustomEventSources\EventSourceExample.Company-MyProject-WebApp.etwManifest.dll" /mf:"C:\CustomEventSources\EventSourceExample.Company-MyProject-WebApp.etwManifest.dll"

Comment: Have you activated the option to show analytic logs in the Eventviewer options?

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I did't know I have to activate it explicitly.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [default the Analytic and Debug are disabled](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749492.aspx):

> Analytic and Debug logs are disabled by default. When enabled, they
>   can quickly fill with a large number of entries. For this reason, you
>   will probably want to turn them on for a specified period to gather
>   some troubleshooting data and then turn them off again. You can
>   perform this procedure by using either the Windows interface or a
>   command line.

You have to [manually show them in the Eventviewer options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766275.aspx):

> 1. Start Event Viewer.
> 2. Click the `View` menu. If `Show Analytic and Debug Logs` is selected, Analytic and Debug logs are already visible. No further action is
>      required. If `Show Analytic and Debug Logs` is not selected, select `Show`
>      `Analytic and Debug Logs` to make these logs visible.

[image]